# JDBC - java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

I am trying to execute the below query in Oracle DB through JDBC but its throwing an exception. The exception is:

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

Please suggest what needs to be changed ?

```
String questionQuery = "SELECT PCN_SURVEY_DEFINITION.ID, PCN_SURVEY_DEFINITION.NAME, PCN_QUESTIONS.ID, PCN_QUESTIONS.SURVEY_ID, PCN_QUESTIONS.LABEL, "
                + "PCN_QUESTIONS.TYPE, PCN_QUESTIONS.REQUIRED, PCN_QUESTIONS.COMMENTS, PCN_QUESTIONS.DISPLAY_ORDER "
                + "FROM PCN_SURVEY_DEFINITION, PCN_QUESTIONS "
                + "WHERE PCN_SURVEY_DEFINITION.ID = PCN_QUESTIONS.SURVEY_ID "
                + "AND PCN_SURVEY_DEFINITION.NAME=? "
                + "ORDER BY PCN_QUESTIONS.DISPLAY_ORDER ASC";
```

Comment: Please share the complete code with the statement invocation.

Answer (score 1):

Correct the condition in WHERE clause and check the quotes(") properly where to start and where to end.

```
"WHERE PCN_SURVEY_DEFINITION.ID = " + PCN_QUESTIONS.SURVEY_ID + " AND PCN_SURVEY_DEFINITION.NAME=? " + "ORDER BY PCN_QUESTIONS.DISPLAY_ORDER ASC";
```

Comment: I don't think `PCN_QUESTIONS.SURVEY_ID` is a Java variable; it's a JOIN condition inside the query.

Answer (score 0):

What do you do with the question mark? Maybe you meant to put a column name here of the other table? The one before the ORDER BY? Or are you using a prepared statement afterwards? Try removing this condition temporarily for testing purposes:  `"AND PCN_SURVEY_DEFINITION.NAME=? "`

```
 "WHERE PCN_SURVEY_DEFINITION.ID = PCN_QUESTIONS.SURVEY_ID " + "AND PCN_SURVEY_DEFINITION.NAME=? " + "ORDER BY
```

Answer (score 0):

Oracle does not suport question mark "?". For variable binding oracle uses ":name" or ":1"

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96584/oci05bnd.htm

Comment: This is incorrect. The questionmark is a valid bind placeholder for Oracle over JDBC.

Answer (score 0):

I had something similar and had to add the following property in my `application.properties` file (since I am using Spring Boot), this resolved the issue for me without having to change any of my SQL

```
spring.jpa.database=oracle
```